# Django allauth redirect to signup route for user that registered with password and login with social login

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I used Django allauth for user authentication in my app. When a user registers with google account with email and manual password and then tries to login with google social login, Django allauth redirect user to accounts/social/signup/ route and asks user to enter email address and after entering email address, tells user that email address already exist!
I read allauth documentation and configurations, but nothing works for me, here is my confirmation in settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = ('username_email')
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "mandatory"
ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = 'https'
####
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

Comment: *email address already exist!* - when user creates their account manually by provide username & password it stored only in ***User*** table but when user tries to login with social account then djang-allauth look for existing *SocialAccount* for that user if user don't have any record in *SocialAccount* table then it tries to create it

Comment: In your case you're trying to create user which already have an account but it does not contain any SocialAccount then django-allauth trying to create new user with SocialAccount again that's why you're receving an error about  email already exists you can check for existing account before creating new & if user has one then only create SocialAccount

Comment: How did you resolve this eventually?

Answer (score 0):

I made mine to do kind of 'auto bind existing user'.

settings.py

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'myapp.socauthadapter.MySocialAccountAdapter'
```

myapp/socauthadapter.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
from allauth.account.utils import perform_login

usermodel = get_user_model()

class MySocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin): 
        user = sociallogin.user
        if user.id:  #Already linked
            return          
        try:
            UserObj = usermodel.objects.get(email=user.email)  # if user exists, connect the account to the existing account and login
            sociallogin.state['process'] = 'connect'                
            perform_login(request, UserObj, 'none')
        except usermodel.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

hope it helps